# restructuring groupby array of objects in es6

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, underscore.js, typescript2.0

Here is a data response I have and need to format it as an expected one: based on rowindex need to format array of objects.better solution appreciated.

Input :

```
productdata:[       { rowIndex:1 , columnKey:'productName'},
                    { rowIndex:1 , columnKey:'productID'},
                    { rowIndex:1 , columnKey:'productDate'},

                      { rowIndex:2 , columnKey:'productName'},
                    { rowIndex:2 , columnKey:'productID'},
                    { rowIndex:2 , columnKey:'productDate'},
                    ],
```

expected O/p
productData:

```
[       { rowIndex:1 , columnKey:'productName'},
                    { rowIndex:1 , columnKey:'productID'},
                    { rowIndex:1 , columnKey:'productDate'}],
[{ rowIndex:2 , columnKey:'productName'},
{ rowIndex:2 , columnKey:'productID'},
{ rowIndex:2 , columnKey:'productDate'}],etc
```

Comment: Could you please share the code that you have tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: @palash it is the server response format, based on the row index i need to bind the data in a grid, i am getting an array of objects, I need to group based on rowindex and convert it as an  array of objects for each rowindex.still stuck in this part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create the array

```js
const productData = [
  { rowIndex:1 , columnKey:'productName'},
  { rowIndex:1 , columnKey:'productID'},
  { rowIndex:1 , columnKey:'productDate'},
  { rowIndex:2 , columnKey:'productName'},
  { rowIndex:2 , columnKey:'productID'},
  { rowIndex:2 , columnKey:'productDate'},
];

const result = productData.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const arrIndex = curr.rowIndex - 1;
  if (acc[arrIndex]) acc[arrIndex].push(curr);
  else acc[arrIndex] = [curr];
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this approach using `reduce` function:

```js
var productdata=[ { rowIndex:1 , columnKey:'productName'}, { rowIndex:1 , columnKey:'productID'}, { rowIndex:1 , columnKey:'productDate'}, { rowIndex:2 , columnKey:'productName'}, { rowIndex:2 , columnKey:'productID'}, { rowIndex:2 , columnKey:'productDate'}];

var result = Object.values(productdata.reduce((acc, elem)=>{
   acc[elem.rowIndex] = acc[elem.rowIndex] || [];
   acc[elem.rowIndex].push(elem);
   return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```